# Agora: How to show incoming call notification when the app is terminated?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, agora.io, agora-implementation

I am implementing a video call app using agora in flutter for ios and android using the [agora_rtc_engine](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine).

I use the [agora_rtm](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtm) package to send a local invitation and [callkeep](https://pub.dev/packages/callkeep) to show call notification when the invitation is received.

And it works fine when the app is in the foreground and in the background(not closed).
but the notification is not working when I terminate the app from background.

Is there a way to show call notification when the app is terminated?

Comment: On iOS you will need to use PushKit/ VoIP pushes and this means your app must use CallKit